# R - Shiny Won't Let Me Convert Serial Dates

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a data frame in Shiny that has separate columns for the month and year. I have been trying to turn this into a date object.

```
yearData=2013
monthData=1
dateData = ymd(paste(yearData, monthData, "01", sep="-")
```

This returns the proper date object if I run it in the R console (01-01-2013), but when I run the same code in Shiny it for some reason converts it to the serial date (15706). I've tried to troubleshoot this:

```
#This converts the serial date to a character string in the date format, 
#"2013/01/01"
dateData2 = format(as.Date(dateData, origin = "1970-01-01"), "%Y/%m/%d") 

#This then converts it back to a proper date object
dateData3 = as.Date(dateData2)
```

Again, if I try this in the R console, I have no problem converting a serial date into a date object. However, when I run it in Shiny, it once again converts dateData3 back into a serial date.

[Here's a screenshot of what Shiny is returning when I run that same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htwdA.jpg)

Does anybody have any suggestions on some other methods I could try to convert the serial date in Shiny into a date object?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the date object is being converted when the table is being rendered.

```
dateData4 <- as.character(dateData3)
```

This is what I do before I render a table or write it to a csv.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you would do that. Why would I convert the serial number into a character? And why would I do it before rendering the table? Just to be clearer, my goal is to take the serial date -- however and whyever Shiny is converting it into such -- and turn it into a standard "%m-%d-%Y" date object so that I could make a time series graph.